# How long does it take for deleted profiles to disappear from google search results?

Tags: facebook, search-engines, google-search, google-plus

I apologize if this is the wrong stackexchange site, but I did see questions tagged with Facebook/Google+ and what not.

Anyway, I deleted a few online profiles I had (g+, soundcloud, etc...) however they still appear on google search results. So the first few links that come up when searching for my name are all deleted pages. I was wondering how long it would take for them to disappear and be replaced by something active, like my Github for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't give details of how often they re-index sites, but it is generally known that they index popular sites more often.  See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38049/how-long-does-it-take-for-google-to-re-index-pages-or-update-the-link-titles